# Why mojolicious action is not called?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have routes configured as:

```
$rn =  $rn->any( '/users',  sub{ my $c =  shift; $DB::single =  1; 1; } );  # first cb
$rn =  $rn->any( '/me',     sub{ my $c =  shift; $DB::single =  1; 1; } );  # second cb
$rn =  $rn->any( '/avatar' )->to( 'avatar#test' );                          # action
```

When I do request `GET /users/me/avatar` I get second callback is executed.

But I expect `avatar#test` action to be run.

I am confused. The [DOC](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Route-to-callback) states:

> The cb stash value, which won't be inherited by nested routes, can be used to bypass controllers and execute a callback instead.

The `/avatar` is nested into `/me` and `cb` should not be inherited, but at dispatch time I get `stack` with `cb` value. Here is dump:

```
[
  { action => "test", cb => sub { ... }, controller => "avatar" },
]
```

May someone please clarify. What why second `cb` is present in stack while the DOC states is should not?

Answer (score 1):

While this do not describe why `cb` is called when it should not be. We can take control a bit over that:

```
$rn =  $rn->any( '/users' );
$rn =  $rn->any( '/:id', \&setup_id )->inline( 1 ); # Enable: /users/me/avatar
$rn =  $rn->any( '/avatar' )->to( 'avatar#test' );
```

The `inline` options force `setup_id` sub will be called always. At this sub we setup param `id` by current users. So instead of `/users/23/avatar` we can write `/users/me/avatar`:

```
sub setup_id {
    my $c =  shift;
    my $id =  $c->param( 'id' );
    # TODO: Should we replace $c->stash->{ id } too?
    $c->param( id =>  $c->uid )   if $id  &&  $id eq 'me';
    return 1;
}
```

*TIP: Do not forget to `return 1`*